# Video capture/record library of desktop/screen " pc not mobile " [c++/Qt]

Tags: c++, qt

so I've been searching for something like this , either library or a way to do this but either it's for mobiles or it's not for noobs :D

Basically I want to capture a full screen video where the user can stop/start/ save the video in many formats.

I've thought of capturing the screen " images " and combine them but it's going to take a lot of cpu power I think and I think there's a better way.

Comment: Use code of some open source product like http://sourceforge.net/projects/camstudio/?source=directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a Qt way for doing this perfectly. You can use `QPixmap::grabWindow` to take a pixmap from a window or take screen-shots like [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/desktop-screenshot.html) repeatedly and combine them to form a video. But these are not optimal and i doubt it can please you by taking smooth videos.

You need to use platform specific features and libraries. on Linux you are better to use OpenGL or X shared stuff directly. On windows it is best to use Directx and mac works best with OpenGL.

[SimpleScreenRecorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/) is a Linux based screen recorder written in Qt. It is such nice and easy to use tool. It enables you to recored the entire or part of the screen as well as the audio. It is multi-threaded and so smooth and supports many video codecs.

SimpleScreenRecorder is licensed under GPL. You can download the source and take a look at it.